# Grid with checkbox column not editable

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, bindingsource

I'm new with c#.
I have a GridView + BindingSource.
I fill my binding source with list of items like this:

```
        public class ListItem
    {
        public DbObject EntityObject { get; set; }
        public bool Used
        {
            get
            {
                return EntityObject != null;
            }
        }

        public int Id
        {
            get
            {
                return EntityObject == null ? 0 : EntityObject.Id;
            }
        }

        public string Name{
            get
            {
               return EntityObject == null ? "<no name>" : EntityObject.ToString(); 
            } 
        }
    }
```

Data shows in Grid as fine. But i can't check or uncheck checkboxes in Grid. When i not fill field `Used`:

```
        public bool Used
        {
           get; set;
        }
```

Grid became editable again. 
  Whats cant be wrong here?

**UPDATE**

Now my grid is editable but work not correctly.
I have a 4 raws, 2 raws was checked:

```
1 unchecked
2 unchecked
3 checked
4 checked
```

Now i uncheck raw 3:

```
1 unchecked
2 unchecked
3 unchecked
4 checked
```

Its fine. Now uncheck raw 4:

```
1 unchecked
2 unchecked
3 checked
4 unchecked
```

Now check raw 2:

```
1 unchecked
2 checked
3 checked
4 checked
```

Why Grid work so strange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you have read only property, if you add `set` also you will able to edit

```
private bool temp;

public bool Used
{
    get { return temp; }
    set { temp= value; }
}
```

Comment: Grid became editable. But some strange here. I have a 4 raws in grid. 2 raw was checked. Now i want to uncheck all raw but i can't. I update question please look at it.

Comment: what is the change you made? have you change `Used` property?

Comment: I was add: `set{  var temp = value; }` to `Used` property;

Comment: use  my code with `private bool temp;` and both get and set, don't use `var` in setter

Comment: Your code works. But when i put my own `get{}' i get same result. But thanks for help.